# python update variable in loop and use it in another process

Tags: python, process

Why while loop is ignored in work1? I would like to update value from string to another value in loop and output this value in process work2. Also already tried with Queue, but problem is I have only one variable which I would like to update in work1 and access to it at work2.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value
from ctypes import c_char_p
import time

def work1(string):
    i = 2

    string.value = i
    # while True:
        # print("work1")
        # string.value = i + 1
        # time.sleep(2)

def work2(string):
    while True:
        print("Value set in work1 " + str(string.value))
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    string = manager.Value(int, 0);

    p1=Process(target=work1, args=(string,))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    p2=Process(target=work2, args=(string,))
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Tried running your code, see `Value set in work1 2`. You see different?

Comment: I commented while loop so that it shows current result, after uncommenting it there is no result at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you didn't make your program parallel with two processes, but instead, two processes run in tandem. What you need to do is to start **both** process before any `join`. Like my modification below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value
from ctypes import c_char_p
import time

def work1(string):
    i = 2
    string.value = i
    while True:
        i = i+1
        string.value = i
        print("work1 set value to " + str(string.value))
        time.sleep(2)

def work2(string):
    while True:
        print("Value set in work1" + str(string.value))
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    string = manager.Value(int, 0, lock = False)

    p1 = Process(target=work1, args = (string,))
    p2 = Process(target=work2, args = (string,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
    p1.join()
```

Indeed, if you write the code in this way, the `join` never happened due to the infinite `while` loop.